# Request POST en Django con funcion AJAX en AngularJS (Angular 1)

Tags: python, ajax, python-3.x, angularjs, django

estoy haciendo una función AJAX en AngularJS donde le paso un valor por POST y me devuelve un objeto en JSON.

Mi función AJAX es esta:

```
$http.post('/get_professional_info/', {idProfessional: id}).then(
        function mySucces(response) {
            // Hago mis cosas
        }, function myError(response) {
            // Informo error
        });
```

En views.py puse lo siguient:

```
def get_professional_info(request):
    dic_id = request.POST['idProfessional']
    professional = Profesional.objects.filter(id_profesional = int(idPro))
    # El resto de las cosas...
```

El tema es que debugueando veo que se está enviando la información correctamente. Cuando imprimo el request.POST me aparece esto, que lo definen como un QueryDict:

```
{'{"idProfessional":3}': ''}
```

¿Como se supone que puedo acceder a eso?
Ya probé con

```
request.POST['idProfessional']
```

y

```
request.POST.dict()['idProfessional']
```

Y ninguna funciona.

Comment: Haz intentado imprimir el valor `request.body`

Comment: al parecer el que está mandando mal la peticion es la funcion de javascript..., ya que está usando todo el diccionario como un solo parametro sin valor... deverias ver si hay alguna forma de enviar la peticion de otra forma para obtener bien la adecuada... podrias usar el ajax de jquery...

Comment: Anteriormente lo tenía en Jquery, pero usando Get, después lo migré a Angular y para hacerlo más seguro lo pasé a POST

Comment: sioesi después pruebo lo que me decís

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahí solucioné el problema con este excelente [Gist](https://gist.github.com/gaspardzul/c4375a09b2b5ee11c286) desarrollado por Gaspar Dzul. La explicación y modo de uso se pueden ver [acá](https://www.pythoniza.me/configuracion-de-angular-en-proyecto-django/).
Al parecer Django con AngularJS (Angular 1) son conflictivos por tema de sintaxis y parseo de JSON. Con eso que acabo de pasar alcanza y sobra para resolver el problema.